# How to access value in Json Object Laravel Blade

Tags: json, laravel, laravel-blade

I just want to access the "Elevator" value in this json object.
How to do this in Laravel blade templates ?

thanks !

```
{"delivery_floor":null,"pickup_floor":null,"Elevator":"Yes","Elevator2":"Yes","disassembled":"Yes","reassembled":"Yes","shipment_title":""}
```

Comment: Have you tried decoding the payload? json_decode('{"delivery_floor":null,"pickup_floor":null,"Elevator":"Yes","Elevator2":"Yes","disassembled":"Yes","reassembled":"Yes","shipment_title":""}')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use following code

```
@php $jsonDecodeValue = json_decode($your_variable,true); @endphp
{{ $jsonDecodeValue['Elevator']}}
```

Comment: You have to set the `associative` flag (second parameter in `json_decode`) to `true` if you want to access the properties as an associative array instead of accessing it as an array.